# Visual Studio serial port encoding problem

Tags: visual-studio-2017, serial-port

I am trying to use Visual Studio 2017's serial port to read a string of characters from a remote terminal and it works fine as long as the string doesn't include character 19. For some reason any instances of character 19 in the string are ignored. I've tried 1552 and 28591 encoding, and reading the port using the ReadExisting and Read (to byte array) functions, and character 19 is always lost or ignored by the VS funcions. I've tried different baud rates in case of a speed issues with no success. If I use RealTerm instead of VS to capture the serial data, the complete string including any instances of character 19 is displayed every time. Does anyone have any idea what is going on? My port setup is currently as follows:

```
SerialPort1.PortName = "COM" & CStr(NumericUpDown9.Value)
SerialPort1.BaudRate = 57600
SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
SerialPort1.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
SerialPort1.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
```

So, as above I've tried all combinations of baudrates, encoding and read methods that I can think of, and never see character 19 in the received data.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind: I found that XonXoff handhsaking was enabled for the port elsewhere in the code. With this property set to None all characters are coming through fine now.

Comment: Thanks to share the solution with the community. Please, close the question. If you could detail more the solution, it will be appreciated. Welcome!